# Find the general formula of this sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, recursion

Here is the sequence

```
1 2 2 4 4 6 6 10 10 14 14 20 20 26 26 36 36 46 46 60 60 ···
```

I just know the recursion formula:$\displaystyle f\left(n\right)=1+\sum_{i=1}^{\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor}{f\left(i\right)}$. But I do not know how to find that, or is there any other recursion formula.

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: How to prove that formula and can we find other recursion formula that suited to this sequence.

Answer (score 2):

[OEIS](http://oeis.org/A018819) tells us this is the "Binary partition function: number of partitions of n into powers of 2."

Comment: I just have referenced that website, but I still do not understand it, can you state it more clearly and give some examples?

Comment: What they also tell is that the recursion formula is $a_{2m+1}=a_{2m}$ and $a_{2m}=a_{2m-1}+a_m$.

Comment: But how can I find that recursion formula, if I do not know it.